# Will Perseverance's landing be live streamed?

Tags: mars, rovers, data-transmission, perseverance, public-involvement

I know that the *launch* will be live streamed,  but I am interested in the *landing*.

Is there a plan to make it possible for the general public to get access to landing video as soon as mission control? Will a landing video be broadcasted back to Earth during the actual landing?

Answers to [Could "live" video be transmitted from Mars?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/32295/could-live-video-be-transmitted-from-mars) suggest this is theoretically possible.

Comment: The landing will be recorded in high quality, but Persy will have 2 Mbps to transmit it, so if it's live we'll only have one high quality video, or a few with bad quality 
https://www.businessinsider.fr/us/nasa-mars-perseverance-rover-seven-minutes-terror-landing-video-2020-7 
https://everydayastronaut.com/perseverance-vs-curiosity-whats-new/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found [this article](https://www.space.com/16868-mars-rover-landing-curiosity-events-webcasts.html) for the 2012 Curiosity rover launch which stated that

> NASA Television will be broadcasting live coverage of Curiosity's landing on Aug. 5 beginning at 8 p.m. EDT

(I also found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N9hXqzkH7YA) showing the mission control room during the landing but I don't know if that was shown live)

So, I suppose that it is probable that we will see live coverage of the landing for the Perseverance rover.

Edit: As @uhoh helpfully states, [this article](https://www.businessinsider.in/thelife/news/nasa-added-6-hd-video-cameras-to-its-next-mars-rover-so-we-can-all-watch-the-first-footage-of-a-spacecraft-landing-on-another-planet/articleshow/77169642.cms) shows that

> NASA added 6 HD video cameras to its next Mars rover so we can all watch the first footage of a spacecraft landing on another planet

Comment: It seems to me the OP was asking for video of the landing, not video of mission control during the landing

Comment: I was unable to find any information regarding if there will be a video of the landing, but if the mission control is shown then the general public will get access to the landing video as soon as mission control.

Comment: I think you can add a few quotes from [NASA added 6 HD video cameras to its next Mars rover so we can all watch the first footage of a spacecraft landing on another planet](https://www.businessinsider.com/nasa-mars-perseverance-rover-seven-minutes-terror-landing-video-2020-7) and have a complete, definitive answer.

Comment: But it will certainly not be live - from the article @uhoh suggests "After stashing gigabytes' worth on unprecedented footage, NASA doesn't expect to see it on Earth very quickly. "We'll bring that imagery back over the first couple weeks on the surface," Wallace said."

Comment: @WiggotheWookie that may apply specifically to HD video, but 1) the video streams from those cameras could also be transmitted live with reduced resolution. That's common, even [SpaceX live videos were uploaded later in higher resolution](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/17510/12102) and 2) Perseverance has [23 cameras](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/42091/12102) and those six may not be the only ones capable of providing video!

Answer (score -1):

> Answers to Could "live" video be transmitted from Mars? suggest this is theoretically possible.

No, they don't.

Imagine having 1-3m (or more) parabolic antenna deployed during landing and precisely directed to Earth.

An aerodynamic nightmare.

Edit:
According to https://mars.nasa.gov/mars2020/spacecraft/rover/communications/
there is an "up to 2 megabits per second" to the relayer orbiter, so a medicore real-time video may be possible.

Comment: The time and date for Perseverance's EDL (entry, descent and landing) is fixed and was chosen for factors including communications. Likely there will be a Mars orbiting satellite overhead that will pick up UHF or VHF signals and relay them back to Earth a bit like the MarCO cubesats and MRO did for InSight [1](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/33131/12102), [2](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/26773/12102), [3](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/32213/12102) and especially [4](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/26786/12102)! So there's no need for Perseverance to deploy a large antenna.

Comment: Yeah, that's what relay spacecrafts are for.

Comment: Also see [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/44858/12102) to *How could the landing date of Perseverance Rover be fixed irrespective of 26 days launch window?*